# A particular sum involving product of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I am encountering a particular sum involving binomial coefficients, and I am looking for a possible closed-form solution. Here is the sum: suppose we are given two real numbers $a \in (0,1)$ and $b \in (0,1)$, and a positive integer $N \in \mathbb{N}$. The sum is
\begin{equation}
f(N,a,b) = \sum_{i=1}^N \cfrac{\binom{a}{2i-1}}{2i} \binom{2i}{i} b^i.
\end{equation}

Here, since $a \in (0,1)$, we have $\binom{a}{2i-1}=\frac{a(a-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(a-(2i-1)+1)}{(2i-1)(2i-2)\cdot\cdot\cdot2 \cdot 1}$. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Using a CAS, I found a closed form which is not very "funny"; it involves hypergeometric functions. Are you willing something of such high complexity ?

Comment: The closed form is a complicated formula involving a generalized hypergeometric function. What do you expect to do with it ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks a lot. Did you find the closed-form solution by using Mathematica ?

Comment: @JJacquelin Thanks a lot. How did you find the closed-form solution ?

Comment: @ Richie : Just looking to the pattern of the sum makes think to hypergeometric series, which would require arduous transformation to reduce it to a standard form. So, I answerd without doing the boring calculus. From that time, I askedWolframAlpha : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum+gamma%28a%29*gamma%282*k%29*b%5Ek%2F%28gamma%282*k-1%29*gamma%28a-2*k%2B1%29*2*k*gamma%28k%29%5E2%29+from+k%3D1+to+N

Comment: Sorry, the link above doesn't work. See the other link below.

Answer (score 1):

Another "nice" formula 
$$\frac{\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2} (-a-1),-\frac{a}{2};1;4 b\right)-1}{a+1}-\frac{\Gamma
   (a+1) b^{n+1} \,
   _3\tilde{F}_2\left(1,-\frac{a}{2}+n+\frac{1}{2},-\frac{a}{2}+n+1;n+2,n+2;4
   b\right)}{\Gamma (a-2 n)}$$

I have not been able to find a limit for infite $N$. Sorry for that. Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Note that
$$
\frac{\binom{a}{2i-1}}{2i}\binom{2i}{i}=\frac{a!(2i)!}{2i (2i-1)! (a-2i+1)!i!i!}=\frac{(a+1)!}{i!i! (a-2i+1)!(a+1)}
$$
and also
$$
(1+1+b)^{a+1}=\sum_{0\le i,j\le a+1}\frac{(a+1)!}{i!j!(a+1-i-j)!}b^{j}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

See the link to WolframAlpha
[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20gamma%28a%2b1%29*%282*k%29!*b%5Ek/%28gamma%282*k%29*gamma%28a-2*k%2b2%29*2*k*k!%5E2%29%20from%20k=1%20to%20N)

and the screen copy :

(after correction of a mistake in the binomial coefficient)
[image]

The limit for $N$ tending to infinity is :

[image]

This agrees with the answer given by Claude Leibovici

The result in case $N=$infinity can also be expressed as a Legendre function :

[image]